# How does post data work with Common Lisp?

Tags: post, common-lisp

I have a post route:

```lisp
(defroute admin-post ("/admin" :method :post)
    (&post clientName dbName email)
  (let ((c (write-to-string clientName))
        (d (write-to-string dbName))
        (res (by-email email)))
    (render-template* *admin.html* nil
      :title "Admin Area"
      :clientName c
      :dbName d
      :db-res res)))
```

The value of email is processed by the `by-email` function successfully. But the `c` and `d` values are `nil`.

ive also tried without `write-to-string` but it returns a blank value to the page.

UPDATE

Here is my html. The form names are the same as the defroute params:

```html
<form id="form" action="/admin" method="post">
  
  <input type="text" name="clientName"  placeholder="Enter Client Name"/>

  <input type="text" name="dbName" placeholder="Enter DB name"/>

  <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What routing library is this?

Comment: This is `easy-routes`. And im using `djula` to render the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to know your client side code. What is the HTML form sending the POST request to this URL? Or do you use an Ajax JS call?

Generally if you have a classic HTML form with named fields, your POST parameters should be set, as a string (so no need of "write-to-string").

Here's an example.

```html
          <form class="level-item">
            <input name="q" type="hidden" value="{{ q }}">
                   ^^^^ named parameter

            <input name="title" type="hidden" value="{{ card.title }}">
            <input name="isbn" type="hidden"  value="{{ card.isbn }}" />
            <input name="price" type="hidden"  value="{{ card.price }}" />
            <input name="target" type="hidden" value="1" >
            <input name="q" type="hidden" value="{{ q }}" >


            <button class="{% if card.in-liste-1 %} button is-success {% else %} button is-outlined is-success {% endif %}"
                hx-post="/add-to?target=1"    <------- POST URL
                hx-swap="outerHTML">
              Liste 1 </button>

          </form>
```

My route with defroute:

```lisp
(defroute add-to-list-route ("/add-to" :method :POST) (target title isbn price q)
   (log:info "All params are here: " target title isbn price q))
```

It's nearly a normal form, only the `<form>` element doesn't have a "method=POST" and URL, I am specifying these on the button, on `hx-post`, with [HTMX](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-post/), which I like to update parts of the DOM without a full page refresh.

The important bit is that all the form parameters have a `name`, the same as the `defroute` definition.

When you have to grab a POST body, you can use `hunchentoot:raw-post-data :force-text t`: https://common-lisp-libraries.readthedocs.io/hunchentoot/#raw-post-data_1